# Is tmpfs (linux/ubuntu)on disk or ram?

Tags: tmpfs

On wikipedia, it says that tmpfs is stored on volatile memory rather than persistent storage device. I have done some experiments and come across contradict.

[image]
（My computer environment-->Mac OS/X parallel Ubuntu 16.04 x64 ）
Type

```
free -m
```

give back
[image]

I do not know what "shared" mean. Type

```
man free
```

give back
[image]

Does that mean the "shared" column shows what is Shmem in /proc/meminfo? Keeping typing

```
vim /proc/meminfo
```

give back

[image]

It does mean part of tmpfs on ram.

But I type

```
df -lh
```

give back
[image]

That means part of tmpfs on disk.

I feel confused! Can someone tell me how tmpfs is implemented (on Linux)? Is it on disk or ram on earth? Or neither.

Answer (score -1):

tmpfs is a temporary file system that uses volatile memory, like RAM. Please take a look at the manual page: 
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfs.5.html